# Present Full Screen Modal on Button Press on a screen inside Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

In my app, I've set up a `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs` in `App.js`, and then each `Tab.Screen` is a `@react-navigation/stack` from where all screens related to the selected tab are stacked.

Now I have a login screen `Login.js` which I want to present at multiple locations. For example, I'm letting the user browse the app but when they click certain buttons I want to present the `Login.js` as a full-screen modal if the user is not logged in of course.

Not sure what code to share but here are some snippets:

For my `App.js` I've:

```
...
function App(props) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="QnA" component={QnA} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Tutorials" component={Tutorials} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Student Center" component={StudentCenter} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
...
```

The Screens like `Tutorials.js` is:

```
...
function Tutorials(props) {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Tutorials Home" component={TutorialsHome} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Course Detials" component={CourseDetails} />
            <Stack.Screen name="My Courses" component={MyCourses} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Learning" component={Learning} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}
...
```

As you can see each of the screens is stacked in their respective stack. Now, for example, there is a button in the `Learning` screen which when pressed checks if the user is logged in or not, and if a user is not logged it should present the `Login.js` as a fullscreen modal.

As the Login screen can popup at any time from any screen so I'm not sure where to put it. I know how to do it in iOS (Swift) we simply use `.present` for this type of functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to Navigation in react native even the modal is part of the stack.

So the technique here would be to have a stack navigator on top with the tabs and the login modal and have your tabs on the screen.

The code would be like below.

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootStack.Navigator mode="modal" headerMode="none">
        <RootStack.Screen name="Main" component={MyTabs} />
        <RootStack.Screen name="MyModal" component={ModalScreen} />
      </RootStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And when you open a tab you can have a condition inside the onpress like below

```
    function MyTabs({ navigation }) {
      return (
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Tab1}
            options={{ tabBarButton: (props) => <TouchableOpacity {...props} onPress={()=>{
// You can have your condition to match your logic
              if(true){
                navigation.navigate('MyModal');
              }
              else{
                props.onPress();
              }
            }}/> }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Settings"
            component={Tab2}
            options={{ tabBarButton: (props) => <TouchableOpacity {...props} /> }}
          />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      );
    }
```

**Note**
You will have to maintain the login properly and hide the whole mytabs screen when user is not loggedin.

You can try it in
https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/tabs-and-modal

Comment: I was able to show the screen however `<Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Dismiss" />` is not working. As in how do I dismiss it? I implemented as you described and it works.

Comment: Are there any errors when you press the button ?

Comment: The error is: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.goBack')`

Comment: so navigation is undefined there, do you have a snack or something that i can check ?

Comment: While creating the snack it's working on the snack so I'm tracking now what I'm missing in my actual code :D Hee is the link to the snack though: https://snack.expo.io/@chtalha/navigation-in-react-native

Comment: So all good :), if you have further issues leave a comment

Comment: Is there any reason why I do not have that 'mode' property on my stack navigator?

Comment: you mean headerMode ?