# How can I render a fullscreen dialog from React Native code in a ReactFragment?

Tags: react-native

I have some React Native code embedded in a native app running on iOS and Android. In both cases it's only taking up part of the screen, with the rest rendered natively. So there's a top section (native), a tab bar at the bottom (native) and a main section in the middle of the screen (native in most cases, but for *one* tab I'm now trying to render this using React Native - this is implemented using ReactFragment in Android and RCTRootView in a UIViewController in iOS).

Now I have a button in my React code that I'd like to bring up a *full screen* dialog over the native and React Native content. Most suggestions to use navigation as a way to handle this will only let me control the content within the fragment, but I need to make this full screen; to cover both the content RN is currently rendering and also the surrounding native elements.

Is there an existing mechanism for doing this, or am I going to have to start writing more custom native modules (to trigger navigation to a new full screen native dialog which can bring in React code)? Seems like a problem someone must have faced before...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Present Full Screen Modal on Button Press on a screen inside Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66688548/present-full-screen-modal-on-button-press-on-a-screen-inside-navigation)

Comment: Unfortunately not - navigation can only handle UI that appears within the ReactFragment - anything outside the top scope of the RN content seems untouchable.

Comment: As far as I understand, you can archive this with nested navigation. So you create the main navigation, in the main navigation, you navigate to two screens. One of them is home navigation, and the other is the fragment you want to archive,, They can move to each other, but also for example the header and bottom tabs are not related to each other. Hope you understand what I mean. If I am correct I will write an answer with simple code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [React navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) to achieve this full screen dialog kind of view.

You can use this [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@ayyamperumal/opening-a-full-screen-modal-%7C-react-navigation) to create a full screen dialog over the native and React Native content.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>This is the home screen!</Text>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('MyModal')}
        title="Open Modal"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function ModalScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>This is a modal!</Text>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Dismiss" />
    </View>
  );
}

function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Details</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const MainStack = createStackNavigator();
const RootStack = createStackNavigator();

function MainStackScreen() {
  return (
    <MainStack.Navigator>
      <MainStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <MainStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </MainStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootStack.Navigator mode="modal" headerMode="none">
        <RootStack.Screen name="Main" component={MainStackScreen} />
        <RootStack.Screen name="MyModal" component={ModalScreen} />
      </RootStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all, unfortunately. The issue is that the UI I have is rendered entirely in native code; there's content at the top, a tab bar at the bottom and a series of Android fragments in the middle (and the equivalent on iOS). One of those fragments is rendered using react native using ReactFragment (Android) and a RCTRootView (iOS).

On pressing a button in that react fragment I want to display a *full screen* modal dialog. Unfortunately it seems like all I can do with react navigation is control the content of the fragment that I'm rendering, which is what this snack does.